# Display "/" character in Regex

Tags: regex

I'd like the name of the month with regex.

Of which:

> Image/video date: December

This:

> December

regex: `/[\s\S]*?\s*Image/video date:\s*((?:\S+[^\S\n]?)+?)[^\S\n]*\n[\s\S]*/`

So, I want to get the word "December" after "Image/video date:".

The above regex would work perfectly for me. The only problem with it is that I don't know how to display the "/" character so I can reach the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match a special character in a regex, there is a way to escape it. In your flavor of regex, you'd want to write `\/` to match a forward slash, just as you can do `\[` to match a left bracket without starting a character class.

Answer (score 0):

The '/' is not special in a regex.  Normally you need to delimit it and it is this the character selected to mark the beginning and end of the expressión.  That depends on the language you are using, but normally, if that's the case, you can avoid it being interpreted as the regex delimiter by usin the escape character `\\`.  So, for example, in `vi(1)` you can:

```
:1,$s/\/dev\/\(.*\)/\1/
```

to change all paths of the form `/dev/(.*)` into `\1` (just eliminate the `/dev/` part)

## NOTE:

The avobe command could have been written in `vi(1)` (changing the delimiter) as:

```
:1,$s:/dev/\(.*\):\1:
```